# Matplotlib Interpolate empty pixels

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have a file 'mydata.tmp' which contains 3 colums like this:

```
3.81107 0.624698 0.000331622 
3.86505 0.624698 0.000131237 
3.91903 0.624698 5.15136e-05 
3.97301 0.624698 1.93627e-05 
1.32802 0.874721 1.59245 
1.382   0.874721 1.542
1.43598 0.874721 1.572 
1.48996 0.874721 4.27933
```

etc.

Then I want to make a heatmap color plot  where the first two columns are coordinates, and the third column are the values of that coordinates.

Also, I would like to set the third column in log scale.

I have done this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# import data
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.tmp', delim_whitespace=True, 
                 comment='#',header=None,
                 names=['1','2','3'])

x = df['1']
y = df['2']
z = df['3']

spacing = 500
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), spacing), np.linspace(y.min(), 
                 y.max(), spacing)

XI, YI = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')

ZI = rbf(XI, YI)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sc = ax.imshow(ZI, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
        extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), 
                y.max()], cmap="GnBu", norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=ZI.min(),
                vmax=ZI.max()))

fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax, fraction=0.05, pad=0.01)

plt.show()
```

And I get this Image
[image]

which has all these empty pixels.

I am looking for something like this instead (I have done this other picture with GNUplot):
[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: It looks like one of the plots is wrong. However we cannot find out which one it is, since we do not have the data. What is the data in the region around r=3000, log(E)=3? Is it 0 or is it 10^-7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`cmap.set_bad`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html) to define a color for the NaN values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib import cm
import copy

# Some data
x = np.array([0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
z = np.array([2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])

# Interpolation on a grid:
nrb_points = 101
xi = np.linspace(-.5, 4.5, nrb_points)
yi = np.linspace(-.5, 1.5, nrb_points)

XI, YI = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
xy = np.vstack((x, y)).T
XY = (XI.ravel(), YI.ravel())

ZI = griddata(points, z, XY,
              method='linear',
              fill_value=np.nan) # Value used [for] points
                                 # outside of the convex hull
                                 # of the input points.
ZI = ZI.reshape(XI.shape)

# Color map:
cmap = copy.copy(cm.jet)
cmap.set_bad('grey', 1.)

# Graph:
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, ZI,
               #norm=colors.LogNorm(),
               cmap=cmap);
plt.colorbar(label='z');
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko');
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y');
```

the result is:

[image: example_with_set_bad]

I would also use [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) instead of RBF method for the interpolation. Then, point outside the input data area (i.e. the convex hull) can be set to NaN.